# Firefox mousemove bug with css perspective enabled

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

The item **completely** comes out of the box when when the cursor is near the bottom edge. There's an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/jufwvLsp/16/

My Browser Version: Firefox Developer Edition 88.0b9 (64-bit)
OS: Arch Linux

How can this be solved? It works perfectly in Google Chrome

```js
const player = document.querySelector('.player');
const field = document.querySelector('.field');

field.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  player.style.top = e.offsetY-25 + 'px';
  player.style.left = e.offsetX-25 + 'px';
});
```

```css
body {
  perspective: 1250px;
}

.field {
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  transform: rotateX(65deg);
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
}

.player {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="field">
  <div class="player"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My Firefox is Firefox 86 and it's working for me. I don't know exactly what behavior is desired by the explanation but in both browsers the behavior is the same

Comment: On firefox 87, the white square completely comes out of the box too